# dynamically populating a combobox with database data issue

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to populate my combo box with incremental ID's from my ms access database, when I run my program the program runs fine although there is no data inside the combo box and no error given from the console. Can anyone have a look through my code to see how I'm going wrong?

```java
private JComboBox comboBox;
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    ResultSet vResults;
    Statement vStatement;

void updatecombo() throws SQLException { 
        
    try {
        con = connectionz.getConnection();
        vStatement = con.createStatement();
        String vQuery = "SELECT Book_ID FROM books";
        vResults = vStatement.executeQuery(vQuery);
        while(vResults.next()) {
            comboBox.addItem(vResults.getString("Book_ID"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOarw.png)

[empty list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk87C.png)

Comment: Are you sure that the program runs fine? Hard to check for errors if you just discard any possible exception.

Comment: Add `e.printStackTrace();` when catching the exception to find out what's wrong.

Comment: Can you try logging everything in the while loop? like this: `String id = vResults.getString("Book_ID"); System.out.println(id);` We don't even know if the connection is successful or even if you fetch the right data.

Comment: Hi, I wasn't printing the exception out thanks for pointing that out, this is what's printing to the console 
'Cannot invoke "javax.swing.JComboBox.addItem(Object)" because "this.comboBox" is null'

Answer (score 1):

The issue was, I wasn't initialising the combo box correctly. Thanks for the comments I was completely overlooking that I wasn't printing the exception and getting to caught up in the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If "Book_ID" is really a string and not a numeric, problem might be with connection. If no errors exist, it might be connected to duplicate server with no data in it.

```
vResults.get**String**("Book_ID")
```